# Protobuf is getting installed without mentioning it in pod file

Tags: swift, cocoapods, protocol-buffers

I am running into an odd problem with my Swift project. Below is my pod file. I am using Swift 3. Now when I run pod install, I always end up seeing

```
Installing Protobuf (3.2.0)
```

Now I don't have this pod mentioned anywhere in the pod  file. Why is it getting installed ? This framework causes some 200+ warnings with Swift 3 and my project works without it ( I delete it from the scheme), so just want to find out where this is coming from and delete it.

```
# platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'randomApp' do
    use_frameworks!

       pod 'Firebase'
       pod 'Firebase/Auth'
       pod 'Firebase/Database'
       pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
       pod 'Firebase/Core'
        pod 'Firebase/Storage'
        pod 'MRProgress'
        pod 'Reachability'

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other framework you're using is using it as a dependancy.

Comment: yea, trying to figure out which one as my simulator will run perfectly fine without this framework.

Comment: pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

Comment: Thanks so much. How did you find this ? Just asking so I can figure this out on my own later.

Comment: Process of elimination - Most frameworks will have their dependencies in their documentation, but sometimes it's faster to plugin the pods a few at a time to narrow down who the culprit is. :)

Comment: You can also look at the podspecs of your dependencies to see what internal dependencies they have